# Creating separate class for M13Checkbox()

Tags: swift, class, init

I want to create a separate class for m13checkbox() due to frequent occurance in code. What should I pay special attention to? Here's a code I've implemented so far:

```
import Foundation
import M13Checkbox

class TCCheckbox: M13Checkbox {

    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       initialize()
  }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       initialize()
  }

    private func initialize() {
      self.boxType = .circle
      self.tintColor = UIColor.white
  }

}
```